# Django admin filter is not working toexclude after filtering (Help Needed)

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-admin

Hi with this code i can not exclue after filtering

can any one help me

```
 def formfield_for_manytomany(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
    if db_field.name == "company_names_uuids":
        kwargs["queryset"] = models.CompanyName.objects.filter(country_code== request._user_country) and models.CompanyName.filter((company_names__exists, country_code__exists) == None).exclude()
    return super().formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

Comment: `exclue()` is not any method, its `exclude()`.

Comment: yes that was typing mistake, i corrected it, thanks